# Enterprise Library Exception Handling Application Block

Tags: c#, enterprise-library

I have ExceptionPolicy, that catching all System.Exceptions. Now I have issue, how can I change that policy, to not catch FaultExceptions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

catch FaultExceptions explicitly and rethrow it if needed.